# How to escape quotes in a docker postgres command

Tags: postgresql, docker, command-line-interface

I have the following command that I'm running (renamed some variables):

```
docker exec docker_name sh -c 'psql dbname -U joeadmin -c "update table set field='really_longstringwithabunf3493829#@#@#@#@#=';"'
```

When I run this, it will throw the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: ...longstringwithabunf3493829#@#@#@#@#=;
                                               ^
```

How can I escape or retain the single quotes so this will work. Also, if this is just a horrible way of approaching this, I'm open to other suggestions. The use case is making changes to a db on a docker container before exporting data out of it.

Comment: Can you install and run the `psql` client on the host, talking to a published port?  That will save a level of quoting and requires fewer permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with strings can be a bit ugly at times with Docker.  In your case, I would suggest using double-quotes first, then escape inner double-quotes with `\`:

```
docker exec docker_name sh -c "psql dbname -U joeadmin -c \"update table set field='really_longstringwithabunf3493829#@#@#@#@#=';\""
```

A cleaner option would be to create an environment variable:

```
STR="really_longstringwithabunf3493829#@#@#@#@#="
docker exec docker_name sh -c "psql dbname -U joeadmin -c \"update table set field='${STR}';\""
```

Bear in mind that string interpolation happens in the host OS, not in the container (unless you escape the dollar-sign with `\${STR}`

Still cleaner would just be to create a file and then copy it into the container:

```
echo "update table set field='really_longstringwithabunf3493829#@#@#@#@#=';" > ~/myfile.txt
docker cp ~/myfile.txt docker_name:/tmp
docker exec docker_name sh -c "psql dbname -U joeadmin -f /tmp/myfile.txt"
```